# how to install fabric on serviceMix

Tags: fabric8, apache-servicemix

I am using ServiceMix 7.0 Release. A read about ServiceMix that it supports fabric8 out of box. But terminal doesn't have fabric commands(fabric:create, fabric:profile-create etc.), and there is no fabric features available. So currently I am using standalone mode.
Please, help me, how to install fabric8 on ServiceMix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really do that. Instead download and use JBoss Fuse as fabric8 v1 comes out of the box with this product.